# Magento AOE Scheduler not starting

Tags: php, magento, cron

After updating my Magento installation to 1.9.1, orders emails stopped working.
So I've read a tutorial that explains to install AOE Scheduler and set up CronJob.

So I did, but I can't open his configuration: every time I go to System --> Scheduler --> Schedule configuration I get this error, and I don't know how to fix.

```
No configuration found for code "mailup_mailupsync"
```

**NB: I don't have mailup addon installed**

Comment: This exception is thrown when AOE Scheduler tries to load a Model (from configuration XML) - so you must have reference to mailup_mailupsync somewhere in a configuration file that is being loaded.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply: where do you suggest to search for that configuration? I don't know where to find that model.
In fact the first error is
    #0 /home/xxSITENAMExx/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Configuration.php(81): Mage::throwException('No configuratio...')

Comment: Depending on how you have your sourcecode set up, I'd search all config.xml files for the string "mailupsync" for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was posted two years ago, but I ran into this problem today with Magento 1.9.3 and AOE Scheduler last version. There is no solution on the Internet. So, I am writing it here, should anyone need it.

Mailup is an email marketing SAAS like Mailchimp. They provide a module for Magento integration. Their code, apparently, is not exactly clean.

When installed, the Mailup module will create a task in Magento. The task syncs local data with the user account in Mailup. If the module is removed or disabled (setting "false" in the configuration file), the task remains orphaned and AOE Scheduler generates the error report.

Setting the Mailup cron to "disabled" in AOE Scheduler does not solve the issue.

- So, in /app/etc/modules I opened "MailUp_MailUpSync.xml" and set the active status to "false".
- Then, I opened the Magento db with Phpmyadmin. In table "core_config_data" I removed the row that configures the cron task for "mailup_mailupsync".
- Finally, I removed the module files with an FTP client. I found them using a local copy of the module.

Important: I am sure that I will not need the Mailup module in the future. This is important to know, because upon reinstall or reactivation of the module, it is not sure that it will re-create the cron task. The module does not "know" that it has been deleted!